# Node.js WebRTC client

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I am looking for a [webrtc](/questions/tagged/webrtc) implementation for [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js)
to transmit data from a **nodeJS client** to another webRTC peer.

So in my case the nodejs application is **not** the server but a client.
Does such a node module exist?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Do you want to transmit data from some kind of non-WebRTC client (running on Node) to a WebRTC app? For a simple example of video chat using WebRTC clients running on Node, with Socket.io for signaling, check out the codelab at http://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab.

Comment: Excatly - I wrote a Chrome Extension which is installed on multiple devices.
Those extension instances communicate with WebRTC (connection brokering is done using peerjs). Now I am trying to transmit notifications from multiple nodejs applications to the browser extensions.

Comment: did  you find a way to make it work? I'm also trying to do this.

Comment: Any follow up on this? Wondering also if you ever found a working solution for the webrtc client.

Comment: @jantimon Any new developments that you cam across? I am looking for the same solution.

Comment: No correct answer marked, so which solution did you use ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I came along the same problem and stumbled upon these two gems:

https://github.com/helloIAmPau/node-rtc
Sadly it is lacking any documentation.

However
https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc
seems more reliable to me.

Comment: Node-rtc author has joined efforts with node-webrtc team. He was still doing some progress on it's library, but now seems it's abandoned. Definitely, I think the way to go is using node-webrtc.

(Disclaimer: I've commited several patches to node-webrtc and follow the project actively)

Comment: the first link is out of the games. Error 404 :-/

Answer (score 4):

How about `simple-peer` and `rtc-everywhere`?

https://github.com/feross/simple-peer

https://github.com/contra/rtc-everywhere

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [licode](http://lynckia.com/licode/install.html#licode). Their open source webrtc multi-point video conferencing bridge that runs on top of node.js. Their server acts as a webrtc client, which then bridges audio/video to other webrtc clients. You might be able to reuse some of their c++ code that uses libnice(for ICE protocol) and libsrtp(for SRTP stack), and then wrap it inside of your own node.js module to create a successful webrtc client.

Obviously most of their code you don't need, but I think their server gives a good example of a working SDP that you need to send back to the browser in order to establish a successful webrtc connection.

Comment: Problem is licode is a MUC instead of a WebRTC module/wrapper for Node.js, so they use their own API... :-(

(I asked to them just this question some days ago because I know them personally).

Comment: True, but they do implement the SRTP layer, and the ICE protocol; and they expose it in node.js via a module. So I thought that might some interesting code to @jantimon to check out and build his own node.js webrtc module in order to communicate with his other webrtc endpoint(i.e. Chrome extension).

Comment: So, as Licode guys commented/suggested, it should be easy to create the WebRTC API compatible Node.js module on top of their API or recicling fragment of the code of their implementation (it's free software anyway), are you saying this?

Comment: Yes, I think it is a great start. I tweaked my comment a little bit to be more precise. But I think licode is a good example, because it it  already acts as a simple webrtc client which receives SRTP traffic(via ICE) from another webrtc client, and the it bridges it to any other webrtc connections that are interested in receiving this traffic.

Comment: Interesting... I would give it a try but currently don't have time :-(

Comment: If i use node-webrtc for mcu what is limit  of peer's

Answer (score 2):

There is one more WebRTC wrapper for node
https://github.com/vmolsa/webrtc-native.

Supports data channel as well as media streams.

Has support for linux, mac and windows.

WebRTC codebase is synced frequently.

Update:
There's a light datachannel only implementation, supports linux/mac/windows
http://www.meshcommander.com/webrtc

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: the solution below doesn't actually supply video to the server.  I'm not sure what the best (Node) solution for that is.  In C++, try libJingle.

It sounds like webrtc.io will allow you to create a node application that is a peer.  See the github project here: https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io.

There doesn't appear to be super-active development on the project at the moment, but there are 100 forks of it, and the node module is being downloaded 500 times a month right now, so it seems like people care.

#### Example code from the project -- client side

```
<video id="local" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
<video id="remote" autoplay="autoplay"></video>

<script src="/webrtc.io.js"></script>
<script>

  // note: make sure hostname available to all connecting clients
  // (ie. probably not `localhost`)
  rtc.connect('ws://yourserveraddress:8001');

  rtc.createStream({"video": true, "audio":false}, function(stream){
    // get local stream for manipulation
    rtc.attachStream(stream, 'local');
  });

  rtc.on('add remote stream', function(stream){
    // show the remote video
    rtc.attachStream(stream, 'remote');
  });

  // more rtc callbacks are available
</script>
```

#### Server side

```
var webRTC = require('webrtc.io').listen(8001);
```

Comment: This looks like a typical websocket connection from the server (nodejs) to client (browser).

Comment: Nothing special! Tried it. The setup above makes a video conference room, so no browser-to-server video!

Comment: Has anyone tested using this library on a server? The server code doesn't appear to interact with WebRTC at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to establish a WebRTC data connection from node.js to browser with the [serverless-webrtc package](http://blog.printf.net/articles/2014/07/01/serverless-webrtc-continued/) which uses the [wrtc package](http://www.npmjs.com/package/wrtc) as WebRTC implementation.

Unfortunately, when I try using wrtc module with signalling libraries like PeerJS or EasyRTC, the connection is not establish (the error message is "ICE failed"). If anyone has had any success with using any high-level libraries on top of wrtc, I would be grateful for the information.

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://github.com/HefnySco/node-webrtc-native) provides video streaming from native to web. i.e. no need for browser to capture video, and it broadcast  video to client browser. There is a [websocket example](https://github.com/HefnySco/node-webrtc-native/tree/master/examples/node2browser_ws) that works just fine.

Your challenge actually is to build and link webrtc.node, and it is all explained in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this implementation : https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC

I have used it for my projects and it was very easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out too,

WebRTC Datachannels for Node.js
`https://github.com/nodertc`