# Send audio to Nodejs in a bufferred and efficient way - perhaps with WebRTC

Tags: html, node.js, audio, streaming, webrtc

I would like to accomplish something like this in the browser but plugin-free.

It's described in a fully functional Linux command line and in pseudocode:

```
$ arecord -d 5 -f dat -c 1 -f S16_LE -r 8000 |\
  speexenc - - |\
  curl -X PUT "https://api.example.com/record-sound" -T -
```

Pesudo-code:

1. Open the mic,
2. Open the connection to the API endpoint
3. Read bytes from the mic on the rate of 8000 Hz (wave pcm signed 16-bit little endian mono 8000 Hz)
4. Encode the bytes to Speex in chunks (http://speex.org)
5. Write the byte chucks you get from Speex encoder to the webservice request body in chunks - this a lot of bandwidth is saved and bytes are sent as soon as they're available
6. When mic stops giving results (either by a timer `-d 5` or stopped by the user, flush the request body and `send` the request.
7. Wait for JSON (or anything else) results in response body

Obviously this is a Linux command line but the algorithm have been successfully applied on:

1. Linux - using the command above
2. iOS - iPhone and iPad
3. Java2SE on Windows

I would like to achieve the same goal **"efficient and fast streaming from microphone to a server"** on the browser (old browsers are not my concern now). It doesn't have to be a REST server, WebSockets or whatever is possible are as good. Also **Node.js** based solution is prefered.

What I have tried so far:

- Successfully used a [VideoIO.swf](http://code.google.com/p/flash-videoio/) which is a Flash based solution and [RTMPLite](http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/) on the server to receive video. It's actually a very good solution in terms of functionality except that:

  - It requires user approval through very bad UI
  - It's not a standard way of doing web and don't allow good error detection and such
- Successfully used `getUserMedia` to upload the sound through [recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) and `XHR2` it works find except that:

  - It is actually slow because XHR2 needs full data before request can be made using `xhr.send(data)`
  - It is even slower since I could only upload `wav` format which is way bigger in size compared with `ogg` and `opus`
- Researched on the use of WebRTC but couldn't find any resource that mentioned anything other than peer-to-peer connections

Comment: **Update:** It seems that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19147635/161278) provides a solution

Comment: Another **update:** [XHR2 is not streaming](http://maxogden.com/a-proposal-for-streaming-xhr.html) at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked a related question "[How can I use Opus Codec from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548629/how-can-i-use-opus-codec-from-javascript)" to seek other alternatives, and the answers there apply here to some extent:

**Brad:**

> Unfortunately, it isn't currently possible to access browser codecs
>   directly from JavaScript for encoding.  The only way to do it would be
>   to utilize WebRTC and set up recording on the server.  I've tried this
>   by compiling libjingle with some other code out of Chromium to get it
>   to run on a Node.js server... it's almost impossible.
>
> The only thing you can do currently is send raw PCM data to your
>   server.  This takes up quite a bit of bandwidth, but you can minimize
>   that by converting the float32 samples down to 16 bit (or 8 bit if
>   your speech recognition can handle it).
>
> Hopefully the media recorder API will show up soon so we can use
>   browser codecs.

**OmarIthawi:**

> One way to do it is to compile [Opus to Emscripten](https://wiki.xiph.org/OpusRelease#Release_management_.2F_marketing_work) and hope that
>   your PC can handle encoding using JavaScript. Another alternative is
>   to use [speex.js](https://github.com/jpemartins/speex.js).