# WebRTC PeerConnection client nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, webrtc

I'm trying to get WebRTC PeerConnection client on ubuntu to work with nodejs.

First I tried `wrtc` (https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc). I manage to run the client, but I cannot seem to fetch the the data stream. I've noticed the the RTCPeerConnection/PeerConnection on this module have different functions/implementation than when I run inside chrome. So I went looking for another nodejs PeerConnection.

I tried:
https://github.com/Rantanen/node-peerconnection

The already compiled version throws an error: `_ZN6webrtc17BitrateController23CreateBitrateControllerEv`

I figured that to get it to work properly, I have to compile the peerconnection on my machine.

I've followed http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started and compile webrtc in the directory: `/home/myuser/.webrtc/`.
I have `/home/myuser/.webrtc/trunk/out/(Debug/Release)`.
I have `peerconnection_client` executable.

Next I cloned: https://github.com/santiago/node-peerconnection (another implementation, with a make file).
When I'm trying to run the makefile (`make WEBRTC_ROOT_PATH=/home/myuser/.webrtc/trunk`)
I get the error:

```
src/node_peer_connection_client.h:9:18: fatal error: node.h: No such file or directory
 include <node.h>
```

I have `/usr/include/nodejs` (and `/usr/include/node` symlink). I've noticed that there's an src dir inside (`/usr/include/node/src/node.h`).

Other things I tried:

https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc

https://github.com/Raynos/peer-connection

Basically, I'm trying to get a PeerConnection client that has been compiled on my machine to work with nodejs.

Any help will be appreciated ;)
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Trying to get the same thing working myself though webkit webrtc stuff is not on node

Comment: question is similar to the one asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872712/node-js-webrtc-client/33919846#33919846

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising: https://github.com/vmolsa/webrtc-native

Usage Example:
https://github.com/vmolsa/webrtc-native/blob/master/examples/node2browser/index.js:

API:

```
WebRTC.RTCPeerConnection

WebRTC.RTCIceCandidate

WebRTC.RTCSessionDescription

WebRTC.RTCDataChannel

WebRTC.MediaStream

WebRTC.MediaStreamTrack

WebRTC.getUserMedia

WebRTC.getSources
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it ;)

Answer (score 0):

node-webrtc suppose to be the good choice for the time being, the project is alive. If you have any problems you should post an issue there.