# webRTC in node.js

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I'd like to use webRTC in node.js to manage mixed connections involving peer on browser and nodejs.

I did some tests and searches, I tried using [wrtc](https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc) or [webrtc-native](https://github.com/vmolsa/webrtc-native) but in both cases I can't get them works getting builded binaries or rebuild them (tried on Debian 8, Ubuntu 14 and 16). It also seems the projects are discontinued and I found only articles having 2-3 years old.

I'm looking for advices about modules or libraries to use, or how to make wrtc or webrtc-native works.

Comment: `manage mixed connections involving peer on browser` Please elaborate what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @SasiVarunan I'd like to connect browser-browser, browser-nodejs, nodejs-nodejs using as webRTC PeerConnection does

Comment: If you 'd like to use Webrtc Media handling on server side i'd recommend `mediasoup`, `kurento`, `freeswitch` etc

Comment: @SasiVarunan thank you, really appreciate this hint. What about client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered wrtc version 0.0.60 it's ok, so just use that version and webRTC on node.js works

Comment: Sorry, I don't know

Answer (score 5):

1. **NodeJs a simple mesh type media network.**

   express module - web server to serve your html client

   socket.io - Signalling server to exchange SDP and ICE candidates

   Refer [WebRTC-Example](https://github.com/shanet/WebRTC-Example), [webrtc-group-chat-example](https://github.com/anoek/webrtc-group-chat-example) to write   your own client and server model

---

2. **Kurento standalone server (MCU media network)** not in Node but has an npm module for client side

   Refer [Kurento](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2one.html)

---

3. **NodeJS MediaSoup SFU media network**

   Not sure of client model but refer [MediaSoup API](https://mediasoup.org/api/)

Comment: thank you, these resources are very useful, but I still need a node.js client

Comment: Then https://github.com/webRTC-io/webRTC.io also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872712/node-js-webrtc-client

Answer (score 3):

A lot of nodejs libs exists for webrtc. but they share **one problem** ... webrtc.node sometimes does not work on your machine and you have to **recompile** one for yourself to use.

I [made a module](https://github.com/HefnySco/node-webrtc-native) that is a compination of other modules. The module is mainly the code of [webrtc-native](https://github.com/vmolsa/webrtc-native) but the webrtc.node binary is built using script used in [node-webrtc](https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc). That was useful to be as node-webrtc uses [build-webrtc](https://github.com/markandrus/build-webrtc) to compile the code and extract headers, and I find this handy.

It compiles and builds straight forward.... make sure you check the readme to find the tricks.