# I need to know the STUN server hardware requirements for 10 agents with quality 720p for WebRTC Video conference?

Tags: server, webrtc, stun, openwebrtc

We are planning to host WebRTC on premises servers , I went through the documentation of the WebRTC, and need to know:

-Whether these servers can be just services on the same server or a dedicated physical servers?

-The hardware specs for these servers for 10 agents with quality 720p?

Comment: STUN uses very little resources at all; *TURN* is the heavy hitter.

Comment: so what is the recommended specs for STUN server for 10 agents with quality 720p ?

Comment: For ***STUN*** a nano AWS  EC2 instance will do just fine… But again: do you really mean *STUN*?!

Comment: yes i mean STUN server, but we need to make it on-premises not on cloud so the question again: what is recommended specs for this server?

Comment: If you mean STUN server than mentioning "720p" is irrelevant. How often to you expect to have to establish a connection? With 10 agents probably not more often than once a minute or so. For that virtually any box at all will do. AWS EC2 nano instances are something like single-core 512MB RAM machines, which will do just fine in this scenario.

Comment: ok good this specs for STUN server , what about the Media server specs in this case?

Answer (score 1):

[STUN](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) server is used to get your peer's external IP and local IP. It doesn't relay the media. So your video quality doesn't matter here.

`candidate:3343878875 2 udp 1686052606 82.94.27.414 65042 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.124 rport 51765 generation 0 ufrag Ihrz network-id 1 network-cost 10
candidate:3343878875 1 udp 1686052607 82.94.27.414 33374 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.124 rport 64023 generation 0 ufrag Ihrz network-id 1 network-cost 10`

There are plenty of [public STUN server](https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933) around the world including google stun for free. If you wanna host a STUN server then a micro AWS server should do the job.

Your video quality matters if you relay the media using TURN. Since TURN server takes a lot of bandwidth in carrying your video stream to it connecting peers.

Comment: so if i need to make a web rtc on-premises which devices i'll need it like (servers or any other devices) to implement it on-premises

Comment: You don't need any extra devices for webRTC server to work. 
If you want a complete webRTC media server and client. You can try `Kurento` http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what_is_kurento.html. You can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326137/webrtc-in-node-js/42363786#42363786