# p2p video recorder on nodejs from webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, p2p, easyrtc

I need to receive a video stream directly on my nodejs server from a webpage, where the video is recorded. I saw different software but they all provides p2p from a webpage to another webpage. I need p2p from the webpage to the server.

The web client should connect to node.js server, streaming the video in realtime. On the server the video should be recorded and saved in realtime.

How can i achive this ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please note that Stackoverflow is not a coding service, and we expect you to have done your research and come up with an attempt at solving your own task.

Comment: This question is surprisingly broad, and your specifications are very demanding. This may help you get started. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872712/node-js-webrtc-client